# Show loader until view gets loaded (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs, preloader

**Hey all!**

I am **new** to *angular-JS* with almost *1 month experience,* so I **want to show a pre-loader on every response** until data gets loaded. **e.g.,** when i click on Nav-Bar link it *should show a loader* and **autohide when view gets ready** or **second example** is *when i click on signup it inserts data but want to show loader also*. **Please help me to make this out, *Thanks!***

***Regards Usman!***

Comment: Welcome to *StackOverflow*. We are here to help you. Please go through [how to provide a minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please note that ***SO*** is not a code writing site, instead we help you when you provide the code you have done so far. Please edit your question to add some information and code that you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***AngularJS provides extension points which allow you to intercept responses to http requests before they are handed over to the application code. You can use these extension points to provide global exception handling, authentication, or any other type of pre-processing you might need in your app.***

i hope the below article might help you :
http://codingsmackdown.tv/blog/2013/01/02/using-response-interceptors-to-show-and-hide-a-loading-widget/

or you colud simply go for "http://carlofontanos.com/angularjs-show-a-loading-image-on-http-requests/"